# Solvability of polynomials over fields of characteristic zero

Tags: galois-theory

I have a question about solvability of polynomials (in radicals) over fields of characteristic zero.

For a field $K$ of characteristic zero and a number $n$, I would like to ask:

> 1. Does every polynomial over $K$ of degree $n$ have a root expressible in radicals over $K$?
> 2. Is there an algorithm that takes the coefficients of a polynomial of degree $n$ over $K$ and returns a root expressed in radicals over $K$?
> 3. Is there a radical formula $G(c_0,\dotsc,c_n)$ over $K$ that takes the coefficients of a polynomial of degree $n$ over $K$ and returns a root?

Clearly, a negative answer to Q1 implies a negative answer to Q2, and a negative answer to 2 implies a negative answer to Q3.

I understand the situation in case $K=\mathbb{Q}$, and $n \geq 5$: In this case, there is a polynomial of degree $n$ whose Galois group in $S_n$ which is not solvable, and so - all of its roots are not expressible in radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$. So - the answer to Q1 is "no".

Now, if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $n<5$, then the Galois group of every polynomial of degree $n$ is solvable as a subgroup of the solvable group $S_4$, and therefore - all of its roots are expressible in radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$. So, the answer to Q1 is "yes". By looking in Wikipedia, it seems that the answer to Q2 is "yes" too. I don't know what about Q3.

> What is the answer to Q3 for $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $n<5$? **[Answered in the comments: it is "Yes", by Cardano's Formula and Ferrari's Method, which give formulas for the case $n=3$ and $n=4$ respectively. The cases $n=1,2$ are trivial]**

As for general fields of characteristic zero, I found (and understood the proof of) the following result:

**Theorem**: The Galois group of the general polynomial $g(X)=X^n-t_1X^{n-1}+\dots+(-1)^nt_n$ over the field $K(t_1,\dotsc,t_n)$ is $S_n$.

What does this theorem say about solvability of polynomials over the field $K$? Here's what I tried: Let $n\geq 5$. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that the answer to Q3 is "yes" over $K$, and let $G(c_0,\dotsc,c_n)$ be the corresponding radical formula over $K$. I would like to say that $G(-t_1,\dotsc,(-1)^nt_n)$ is a root of the general polynomial (that would be a contradiction), but I'm not sure how to deduce this.

> What are the answers to Q1,Q2,Q3 for a given field $K$ of characteristic zero (for each $n$)?

Comment: Q3 for $\mathbb Q$ and $n=1$: $-\frac{a_0}{a_1}$. For $n=2$: $\frac{a_1\pm\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0a_2}}{2a_2}$ and for $n=3$, $n=4$ there are the formulas by Cardano and Ferrari (which U have never learned by heart)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Are the Cardano and Ferrari formula's really "formulas" or are they algorithms? Don't they contain an "if" some along the way?

Comment: Ok, in this webpage I see that Cardano's formula really is a formula: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula

Comment: And on this webpage, I see that Ferrari's Method really is a formula too: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Ferrari's_Method.

Comment: (so, the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$ is settled)

Comment: Some equations *are* solvable by radicals even if their degree is $>4$; for example $x^n=1$, for any $n$; however some aren't, because their Galois group is not solvable. A method for building an equation with Galois group isomorphic to $S_p$ ($p>3$ prime) is found in many textbooks. Your question 3 is settled in the negative by the fact that $S_n$ is not solvable for $n>4$.

Comment: @egreg: Can you give a reference to such textbook? I'm talking about fields of characteristic zero in general, not only about $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Gils Over $\mathbb{C}$ *every* equation is solvable by radicals, because it's algebraically closed. There's no general formula, though, because the $S_n$ not solvable argument applies.

Comment: @egreg: I see that on $\mathbb{C}$ every equation is solvable is radicals (trivially). Can you spell our in more details the argument that shows that there is no general formula?

Comment: @Gils The formula would work for all fields of characteristic $0$, because the existence of a formula in terms of rational operation and radicals on the coefficients is equivalent to the solvability of the Galois group: once you have the formula you can build a series with abelian factors and conversely.

Comment: @egreg: But if a formula, if I have to take an $n$th root of an element $a$, it's like adjoining a root of $x^n-a$. If $x^n-a$ is irreducible over the 'current' field, then it's OK. But if it's not irreducible, which root do I adjoin? I can adjoin all roots, but I will still have a problem if I need to 'use' that roots later on in the formula.